# Evaluating a Triple Integrals domain?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$\iiint_T$ $x^2y^2z^2 dxdydz$,  where $T$ is the solid bounded by the planes $\quad$ $z= y+1, y+z =1, x=0, x=1,z=0$.

How does one interpret this jargon in order to assign the limits for all the integrals. This is what I have done so far.

$ x=0 ,x=1 ; z=0, z= y+1; y=1-z, y= z-1$

---

$\int_0^1$$\int_0^{y+1}$$\int_{1-z}^{z-1}$ $x^2y^2z^2 dxdydz$

---

I am unsure if this is how one proceeds any advice on how to set this problem up would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a problem like this, I think it helps to draw out as much as you can. Now clearly drawing this in three dimensions can get messy, but notice that the bounds for $x$ are given to be from $x=0$ to $x=1$. We can choose to integrate this last and then disregard it for a bit and deal with just $z$ and $y$.

Now if we draw out the lines $z = y+1$, $y+z = 1$, and $z=0$ on the $yz$-axis (draw $y$ on the horizontal axis and $z$ on the vertical axis), we get that the region bounded by these three lines is a triangle. You should get that the left-most bound is given by $z = y+1$ and the right-most bound is given by $y + z = $, or $z = -y +1 $. We see that the lines intersect at $z =1$. So now thinking back to how you'd set up a double integral, you know it'd be easiest to bound $y$ as functions of $z$ and $z$ as constants. That is
$$z-1 \leq y \leq -z+1 \hspace{1cm} 0 \leq z \leq 1.$$

Now we want to think about this in $3$D as well before we proceed too far. Now the triangle we got lies on the $yz$-plane. This would extend out all along $\mathbb{R}^3$, but the planes $x=0$ and $x=1$ we are given would cut it off, giving us a little region to integrate over.

Thus, we can set up the integral 
\begin{align*}
    \int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1} \int\limits_{z=0}^{z=1} \int\limits_{y=z-1}^{y=-z+1} x^2 y^2 z^2 \, dy \, dz \, dx = \frac{1}{270}.
\end{align*}